# MSIE 6.0 appearing in client header - Indication of bot?

Tags: web-server

On the logs to one of my websites, I always track the client's browser and OS. Every so often I see one with MSIE 6.0 and usually the http_referer field being blank. Since MSIE 6 doesn't exist in the wild anymore, would a good policy simply be to redirect all clients whose user agent contains "MSIE 6.0" to someplace else (as well as all clients whose user agent is blank)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, MSIE 6 does indeed exist in the wild. A lot of companies still mandate it as their standard browser.

Comment: Well, when I trace back the IPs they invariably resolve to somewhere in the peoples' republic of china...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ie6countdown.com/

If you have a look at that, it'll show you where IE6 is being used most.

Tom